# Show a unit disk with max metric is closed?

Tags: metric-spaces

I must show that if $\mathbb R$<sup>2</sup> is equipped with max metric,
d = (($x$<sub>1</sub>, $x$<sub>2</sub>),($y$<sub>1</sub>, $y$<sub>2</sub>)) = max{|$x$<sub>1</sub> - $y$<sub>1</sub>| , |$x$<sub>2</sub> - $y$<sub>2</sub>|}
then the disk
**D** = {($x$<sub>1</sub>, $x$<sub>2</sub>) ∈ $\mathbb R$<sup>2</sup> : $x$<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + $x$<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> ≤ $1$ }
is a closed set.

My attempt (I'm just about two weeks of experience with any of this):

To show **D** is closed, I must show that it contains all of its limit points. So let   *L* = ($x,y$) be a limit point of **D**. As such, it has some sequence S<sub>n</sub> = ( $x$<sub>n</sub> , $y$<sub>n</sub> ) such that this sequence converges to *L* and all of its terms remain in **D**. Since all these terms remain in **D**, we can say $x$<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> + $y$<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> ≤ $1$ for all $n$. Then, by triangle inequality we have
 ($x$<sub>n</sub> + $y$<sub>n</sub>)<sup>2</sup> ≤ $1$

$x$<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> + $y$<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> ≤$ 1 $
Also, since as the limit of n goes to infinity, S<sub>n</sub> $\to$ *L* , I think we can say
 $(x+ y)$<sup>2</sup> ≤ $1$

$x$<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> + $y$<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> ≤ $1$

And that's where I'm completely stuck....assuming any of this is right at all.

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$, all norms are equivalent, then if you prove that it's closed for the metric $d(x,y)=\|(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2\|$, it will prove that it's closed for the norm of maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An elaboration on Surb's comment

For clarity, I'll use $d_\infty((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = \max\{|x_1 - y_1| , |x_2 - y_2|\}$, and $d_2((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2}$.  Observe that for any $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2) \in \Bbb R^2$, $$d_\infty((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) \le d_2((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) \le \sqrt 2 d_\infty((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)).$$  **Thus we say that $d_\infty$ and $d_2$ are equivalent.**

### Problem

I type it once in $\rm \LaTeX$.

> Show that $D := \{(x_1,x_2) \in \Bbb R^2 : x_1^2 + x_2^2 \le 1\}$ is closed in $(\Bbb R^2, d_\infty)$.

Since the OP's way is to construct a convergent sequence $(S_n):=(x_n,y_n)$ in $D$, and suppose that $S_n \to L:=(x,y)$ under $d_\infty$, I will show that $L \in D$ in $(\Bbb R^2,d_\infty)$.

Since $(S_n)$ is in $D$, $\forall n \in \Bbb N, x_n^2 + y_n^2 = d_2((0,0),(x_n,y_n)) \le 1$.

By $S_n \to L$ under $d_\infty$, for any $\epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n \ge N, d_\infty((x_n,y_n),(x,y)) < \dfrac{\epsilon}{\sqrt2}$. $$\forall n \ge N, d_2((x_n,y_n),(x,y)) \le \sqrt2 d_\infty((x_n,y_n),(x,y)) < \epsilon$$

Using the Triangle Inequality,

$$d_2((0,0),(x,y)) \le d_2((0,0),(x_n,y_n)) + d_2((x_n,y_n),(x,y)) \le 1 + \epsilon$$

Since the choice of $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $d_2((0,0),(x,y)) \le 1$.  In other words, $x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \iff L \in D$.  Hence $D$ is closed.

[image: a picture illustrating the problem]
[$\rm \LaTeX$ Source code](https://gist.github.com/VincentTam/7c90d25563ac3370e5d0)